# Swift, how to play sound when press a button

Tags: swift

I'm very beginner of programming and start studying Swift to make a piano app for fun.

I have a trouble to play a sound when press a button.
I've searched some website but I'm too beginner to understand...

http://www.tmroyal.com/playing-sounds-in-swift-avaudioplayer.html
http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/swift-avfoundation/

Could you please tell me how can I play my "C.m4a" sound when press a "PainoC" button?

Here is my "view controller.swift".

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()   
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func PianoC(sender: AnyObject) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I hope it will help you.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
   // make sure to add this sound to your project
   var pianoSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("C", ofType: "m4a"))
   var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()   

       audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pianoSound, error: nil)
       audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }

   @IBAction func PianoC(sender: AnyObject) {
       audioPlayer.play() 
   }

}
```

**Latest Swift 4.2 :**

```
   let pianoSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "btn_click_sound", ofType: "mp3")!)
   var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

   @IBAction func PianoC(sender: AnyObject) {
       do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: pianoSound)
            audioPlayer.play()
       } catch {
          // couldn't load file :(
       } 
   }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i really appreciate. sorry i'm not used to add comment,,, it doesn't work and i replied to you by answering...

Comment: after studying Xcode and Swift for a while and now I understand your answer. It worked! thank you very much!

Comment: Why are you initializing audioPlayer to AVAudioPlayer()?

Comment: @jpheldson Yeah, I noticed that too.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 3**

the syntax is now as follows:
first add `import AVFoundation` on top of the code to have access to `AVFoundation Framework`.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //this is your audio playback instance
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // address of the music file.
        let music = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Music", ofType: "mp3")
        // copy this syntax, it tells the compiler what to do when action is received
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: music! ))
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }

    }
//this runs the do try statement
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func play(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
    @IBAction func stop(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        audioPlayer.stop()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**SWIFT 5**

```
import AVFoundation


class Test {
    
    var player: AVAudioPlayer!
    
    func playAudio() {
        
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sound", withExtension: "mp3")
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
        player.play()
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**In Swift 4:**

```
import AVFoundation
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate {
    let popSound = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Pop", withExtension: "mp3")
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
       do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: popSound!)
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch {
            print("couldn't load sound file")
        }
}
```

Comment: This crashes as it returns nil for popSound. This can be easily fixed using the following code: `let popSound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "pop.mp3", ofType:nil)!`
  `audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: popSound))`

Comment: Please avoid force unwrapping values as it is a dangerous action and may cause unexpected app crashes. Always remember to write as safe as possible code.

Answer (score 3):

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func button1Action(sender: AnyObject) {
        let CatSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Meow-sounds", ofType: "mp3")!)
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: CatSound)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        } catch {
            print("Problem in getting File")
        }
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post [similar answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39435255/2227743). Anyway, if a question already has an answer available, *flag the question as duplicate* instead of answering. Thanks.

Comment: @Eric Aya Look at my code.. It is different from above answer.. I use try and catch method for error handling which is necessary in x-code Version 7.1 (7B91b) for new swift

Comment: I wasn't talking about the answers *here*. The problem is that you've posted an answer *similar to the one you've already posted* on the other page. That's why I told you to avoid posting duplicates and to flag the question instead.

Answer (score 2):

**In Swift 4**

This worked for me try it out.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate{

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }



    @IBAction func notePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let soundURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "note1", ofType: "wav")!)

        do{
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL as URL)

        }catch {
            print("there was some error. The error was \(error)")
        }
        audioPlayer.play()

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 3:**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class QuestionView: UIViewController {

    var btnButton = UIButton()
    var player = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        btnButton.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
        btnButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        btnButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ButtonSound), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    func ButtonSound() {

       do {

           //  make sure to add this sound to your project

           let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Click", ofType: "mp3")

           try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)


       } catch {

           print("Error !")

       }

       player.play()

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want a click effect, the code below will work.
The bird file must be in xcode.

```
self.run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Bird.mp3", waitForCompletion:false))
```