# Cannot play sound when button is pressed because of nil, Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am trying to create a sound when A button is pressed in Swift. Since I do not know how to do that I am following answers regarding that subject on stack overflow. Unfortunately all answers involve passing nil into a paramter, which I cannot do in Swift 2.0. Here is example code of how they play sound when a button is pressed.

[Swift, how to play sound when press a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736470/swift-how-to-play-sound-when-press-a-button)

As you can see answers involve passing nil as an argument into a parameter when initializing the audio player object.

Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize the player use:

```
let audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: yourSoundURL)
```

Comment: Yes thats correct. Also I added this

Comment: do {
      try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
    } catch {
      print("Player not available")
    }

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem! Does it work now? :)

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you

Comment: Awesome! Can you please upvote and accept my answer then? :)