# Playing a sound in a Swift Playground

Tags: swift

How can I play a sound file with AVFoundation in a `Swift` `playground`? Ideally, the file would be in a URL, not in the local drive, but that's not important.

Comment: Any code you tried so far?

Comment: Look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043904/creating-and-playing-a-sound-in-swift?rq=1

Comment: I'm not sure that you can.  

For sure you can create new folder `Resources` under `playground` content and further Playground will find it with path something like:

    playing file:///var/folders/74/d78g19sj65bc6z2n6gjw9n4r0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/applications/YourApp-67685-8.app/Want_You.mp3
 
but `avPlayer.prepareToPlay()` will always returns `false`.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid it must be a bug in the playground implementation

Answer (score 2):

I'm fumbling around in the dark on this one myself, but I think it may be due to some limitation of swift playgrounds.  Consider this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/swift

import Cocoa
import AVFoundation

var error: NSError?

println("Hello, Audio!")
var url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/somebody/myfile.mid") // Change to a local midi file
var midi = AVMIDIPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, soundBankURL: nil, error: &error)
if midi == nil {
    if let e = error {
        println("AVMIDIPlayer failed: " + e.localizedDescription)
    }
}
midi.play(nil)
while midi.playing {
    // Spin (yeah, that's bad!)
}
```

If we run this swift *script* in the terminal, it works fine and plays the midi file, but if you run the code in a playground, you get

> AVMIDIPlayer failed: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio error -1.)

On the positive side, being able to run it in a terminal shows that the code does work.

Answer (score 1):

This works on a project I haven't tried on Playground. First drag your sound to your project and choose to copy for your destination if needed and check "add to target" to your app.

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation


var beepSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("beep", ofType: "aif")!)
func initBeep(){
    beepPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: beepSound, error: nil)
    beepPlayer.prepareToPlay()
}

func playBeepSound(){
    beepPlayer.play()
}
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) { 

    initBeep() 
}
@IBAction func btnPlayBeepSound(sender: AnyObject) {
   playBeepSound()
}
```