# SpriteKit doesn't play any music with either SKAudioNode or SKAction.playSoundFileNamed

Tags: sprite-kit, swift4

I'm struggling with a problem, that neither SKAudioNode nor SKAction.playSoundFileNamed could help me with playing a music, in a project. The audio files format are mp3, wav or m4a

I checked if it works another project. But still it occur. 
I think it would be a reproducible problem so I'll attach my codes here
(* if this, the codes below, worked on your pc please notice me in a comment. )

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import AVFoundation  // Needed...?

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let foo = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "sample")
        self.addChild(foo)
    }

    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        switch event.keyCode {
        case 49:
            let bar = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("bubble", waitForCompletion: false)
            self.run(bar)
        default:
            print("keyDown: \(event.characters!) keyCode: \(event.keyCode)")
        }
    }


    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}
```

I just would like to play sample.wav as background music 
and when Space is pressed, play bubble.mp3 as a sound effect

**Error outputs below**

```
[AudioHAL_Client] AudioHardware.cpp:666:AudioObjectGetPropertyData:  AudioObjectGetPropertyData: no object with given ID 0
```

```
SKAction: Error loading sound resource: "bubble"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is your mute switch/button on?  other thing I would say is that it is not finding bubble or sample because you are not using an extension

Comment: Of course not, and sorry I missed to add error outputs

Comment: Then it is because extension is missing, “bubble.wav”

Comment: It also needs to be in your bundle, not your assets I believe.  I cant remember, but to use the assets I believe you had to do something different to let The player to know to look in the asset

Comment: I've already tried that before. But doesn't make sense -> file extension

Comment: Why doesnt it make sense?

Comment: Sorry I missed words, please forget about 'doesn't make sense'

Comment: Do you mean I cannot use Audio files in Assets.xcassets ?-> files should be in my bundle

Comment: Yes do not use xcassets,  there is a different way to extract it

Comment: Oh I've got it! Thank you. I'll answer myself now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case
Audio files are in Assets.xcassets. 
but that's wrong. 
Just put all audio files under project group.