# Invoking a random timer after button press to trigger a sound

Tags: objective-c, swift

New to the community and coding, but just thought I would ask for some pointers.

Wanting to build an mobile app the essentially plays a sound after a button press in the app. Ideally the sound would be played after the "random" amount of time which I hope to keep from 5-15 seconds.

Not looking for someone to make this, just want some pointers in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

There are many tutorials on how to create a basic UI with a storyboard and connect your button to an action in your code.  You could perhaps start with [this one](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH5-SW1).

You can check out the [`arc4random_uniform`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html) function to generate random numbers, for 5 - 15 it would look something like:

```
let randomValue = arc4random_uniform(11) + 5
```

to do something after a period of time, the easiest way is probably using GCD via [`dispatch_after`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_after.3.html):

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(NSTimeInterval(randomValue) * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // Play a sound
}
```

As for playing a sound, here's a [question about that very topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043904/creating-and-playing-a-sound-in-swift).