# Play click sound whenever I tap on my whole app inside

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avfoundation, xcode10.1

In my app, for a button click or any tap I need to play one beep sound on user click or tap. I added this code in AppDelegate:

```
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
func playSound() {
        let audioFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "/Sound/music1", withExtension: "mp3")
        do {
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioFileURL!)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        audioPlayer?.play()
    }
```

I don't know how to merge or pass these methods to all of my taps and button clicks to play that beep sound. I don't want to add in each button click in each vc. Any help with dynamic solutions for the button click and any touch event in my app?

Comment: You want your entire screen as one button? so when you touch the screen it makes a beep?

Comment: noo....in my app i have many button and navigation bar back button and click events. So when ever any touch action happens,i needs to play that beeb sound with those actions

Comment: So you want every buttons in your view to make the same beep whenever they touch a button?

Comment: yes, And also i have some collection view cell. So if i tap also i need to play that touch sound

Comment: @Asbis any possibilities ?

Comment: I will help you tomorrow.

Comment: @Asbis   Any help on that..i tried all the thing...nothing is worked

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your app or a sketch of what you want it to look like?

Comment: why screenshot needs ?. I added that posted code in appdelegate. So when ever user tap in my app i need to beep the sound...

Comment: oh! Now i understand what you are trying to achieve. Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996497/swift-how-to-play-sound-when-screen-is-touched

Comment: @Asbis   now i will try that...but can u please help me here..its bit urgent :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55294818/reason-firtimestamp-encodewithcoder-crash

Answer (score 0):

Well you can call the function playSound() in every action for the buttons if you need diferentes gestures, like a long press you can use a Gesture Recognizer.

Example if you need play a simple beep when the button has pressed, just call playSound() inside the @IBAction of the button, but you need play a error beep if the user press the button for long period of time, so add a UILongPressGestureRecognizer in your buttons like this:
[image]

So you can link a gesture Recognizer to you code like a simple @IBAction like this:

[image]

But this is just you need diferentes gestures, if you need a simple beep why you no try this:

```
@IBAction func testAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
     playSound()
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, but please read my post. i  asked for dynamic in one place. i no needs to write in all ibaction.

Comment: Well, I can not understand why you need it dynamically. but I did a simple example, and posted in my git look whether it is the answer, or if at least it's a start, this is the link:
https://github.com/TexugoProgramador/tapTest

Comment: You save a position and width / height of buttons in array, so using the location off touch you make a loop in array to compare touch position with buttons position

Comment: dynamically means. In my appdelegate i needs to write that code.And when ever any button click happens i need to call that. like setting nav color default in app delegate for all vc in whole app

Comment: you can make a custom Button class? like this:


class customButton: UIButton {

    func playSound() {
        print("sound played")
    }
    
    override func sendAction(_ action: Selector, to target: Any?, for event: UIEvent?) {
        playSound()
        super.sendAction(action, to: target, for: event)
    }
}


So you just need change the classe UIButton to your customButton